# Object is getting pushed to array, then randomly taken out

Tags: php, laravel

```
$groups = [];

    foreach($data as $user)
    {
        $userGroupId = $user['GroupId'];
        $exists = false;

        foreach($groups as $group)
        {
            $groupId = $group['GroupId'];

            if ($groupId == $userGroupId)
            {
                $users = $group['users'];

                $currentUser = array(
                    'UserId'=>$user['UserId'],
                    'UserName'=>$user['UserName'],
                    'Surname'=>$user['Surname']
                );

                array_push($users, $currentUser);
                $exists = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!$exists)
        {
            $addGroup = array(
                'GroupId'=>$user['GroupId'],
                'GroupName'=>$user['GroupName'],
                'users'=>[array(
                    'UserId'=>$user['UserId'],
                    'UserName'=>$user['UserName'],
                    'Surname'=>$user['Surname']
                  )]
            );

            array_push($groups, $addGroup);
        }
    }
```

So i have an empty array called groups.

The original data is an array of different users including what group they are in which i am trying to sort into an array of groups with an array of users inside.

Everything works fine except when I am trying to push the current user to the users array.

When debugging I have printed the array after pushing and it has pushed fine but when it comes to the next user, the previous users have gone. So its pushed but then taken it out after.

Comment: Isn't this line `$users = $group['users'];` resetting the list of users each time?

Comment: sure but $users is just a reference to $group['users'] which is a refrence so It should push to the root

Comment: why you use `foreach` on `array` empty?

Comment: @AlexanderVillalobos because its only empty at the start. it gets added to during the foreach

Comment: you print currentUser and work???

Comment: in your  `foreach` user put `foreach($data as $key => $user )`

Comment: so next in your currentUser put `'UserId'=>$user[$key]['UserId'],` on all

Comment: Thanks alexander i just needed to push it to a refrence of the array instead of a copy by adding &

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get you right, you should use references:

```
foreach($groups as $group) -> foreach($groups as &$group)

$users = $group['users']; -> $users = &$group['users'];
```

Comment: Ah, I got confused with javascript i assumed it was already a refrence. Thanks